# How is the energy of a particle measured in a Cherenkov detector

Tags: particle-physics, measurements, particle-detectors, cherenkov-radiation

I don't understand how is the energy measured in a cherenkov detector. How is the number of photons radiated related to the energy of the particle or the measure of energy has nothing to do with the light yield ?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Cherenkov detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_detector) and the article on the [Frank Tamm formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Tamm_formula) seem to cover this. Can you clarify what aspect of this is giving you problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cerenkov detectors measure velocity (either above/below threshold for simple detectors or via the opening angle for ring-imaging devices).

Energy depends on both velocity and mass, so *if* you have a reliable particle ID, then the velocity measurement from a Cerenkov device can be used to establish the energy to moderate precision.

Similarly if you know the momentum (say, from a spectrometer) and the velocity then you can deduce the energy.

With neither PID nor velocity a Cerenkov device does *not* measure energy.